# how to write octal constants in MIPS (MARS assembler)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, octal

I would like to specify to MARS that I'm entering an octal number as an immediate operand.

I know that it is possible with Hex-
Something like:

```
li  $t0, 0x24    #this is ASCII '$'
```

Is it possible to do the same with Octal?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing with just `0` yet?

Comment: didn't understood. you mean li $t0, 024 ?

Comment: @ALUFTW: Yes, if you want to load immediate 24 (in octal) prefix de immediate with `0`, i.e. `li $t0, 024`

Comment: For ASCII char values, you can just use `li $t0, '$'` in the first place, instead of needing a magic number and a comment.  Octal could be useful for *other* cases, though, so I hope that's just a silly choice of example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prefix the immediate with 0, like in C:

```
li $t0, 024
```

Thanks to @gusbro

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MARS, qtspim and pcspim don't support the leading-0 for octal.  For example, `024` and `037` are treated as decimal constants, the same as `24` and `37`

You must manually convert to a decimal or hex for SPIM's built-in assembler.